# Doing match grouping in new Regexp object

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to manipulate strings using regex like this:

```
string = '?order=age'
var order_regex_asc = /([&?])order=([a-z])/g;
new_string = string.replace(order_regex_asc, '$1order=-$2');
// The code above will result to "?order=-age"
```

I know the code above will work and that is the kind of logic that I need

However the part where

```
order=([a-z])
```

the value of the order is supposed to be a variable  not a regex. I cannot find a way to insert a variable on a regex statement so I tried the code below

```
data = 'age'
string = 'http://example.com?order=age&order=color&order=gender'
order_regex_asc = new RegExp('[&?]order=' + data, 'g')
new_string = string.replace(order_regex_asc, 'Hi I am a new string');
```

Now my problem on this code is I cannot implement match grouping. I do not know what to do next anymore. Baiscally I just want to change **'?order=age'** to **'?order=-age'** and remember the value of that order is dynamic. It can be height, weight and etc.

**Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/nE6MK7PWb54GkXOdIojn?p=preview**

Remember if you click any of the buttons more than once, it should just play in the GET parameter between putting and removing a hyphen on the value 'age'

Comment: `string.replace(/order=([a-z]+)/i, '-$1')`

Comment: I need the [a-z] to be a variable, imagine that I will click a button and will add a hyphen on that picked variable

Comment: A fancier way to do this is to use `window.URL` features instead of a RegExp. We are often too late in realizing how bad it is to have regular expressions in a project. Even if RegExp seems to resolve everything. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Here is the plunker that I made for my case https://plnkr.co/edit/nE6MK7PWb54GkXOdIojn?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```js
data = 'age'
string = 'http://example.com?order=age&order=color&order=gender'
order_regex_asc = new RegExp('([&?]order=)(' + data +')', 'g')
new_string = string.replace(order_regex_asc, '$1-$2');
console.log(new_string);
```

Comment: Actually yes, so that's how to the Regex matching when creating a new regex object